# Which chart library is better for displaying data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using php and mysqli. I used highcharts in angular2 but now i want to use charts in php. is highcharts still the best when it comes to php? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many options Available for using charts in php some of them are:

- Google charts
- fusion charts
- pChart

Beside them there are alot of other charting libraries like chart.js which can be used with PHP.

Comment: Let me choose from those you have listed. thank you @Shahroze

Comment: @Engxtian I personally like chart.js and google charts :) if you find it relevant plz mark as right answer.

Comment: Thanks, chart.js worked for me.

Comment: then mark it as an answer :)